# Why I get totally empty dataframe when trying to eliminate rows with NA?

Tags: r, dataframe

Having dataframe `df`, I am trying to remove rows with the specific value in the column `Status`.

That's what I do: `df<-df[!df$Status=="ВАКАНСИЯ",]`. As a result I receive dataframe with only NA values.

Interestingly enough, even if I do `df<-df[df$Status=="ВАКАНСИЯ",]` (witthoout negation !) I still receive NA dataframe.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: A few rows and columns (with `Status`) might help to answer.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Just a guess, you might be overwriting your original `df`, try to load data to `df`, then subset and assign the result to a new dataframe `df_subset <- df[ !df$Status == "ВАКАНСИЯ", ]`. Your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

This question can't really be answered (as you don't show your data) but I take a wild guess and say you misspelled your column name. In that case the condition is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE` for any row but `logical(0)` instead, which means all rows are removed:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                 Statuss = c("ВАКАНСИЯ", "Good"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[!df$Statuss == "ВАКАНСИЯ",] #spelled correctly
#>   id Statuss
#> 2  2    Good

df[!df$Stats == "ВАКАНСИЯ",] #misspelled column name
#> [1] id      Statuss
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There is no error or warning displayed in this case.